# Jbpm Script task running before afterProcessStarted of DefaultProcessEventListner

Tags: jbpm

I have a jbpm process, where I have a 
`startNode -> scriptTask -> timer -> scriptTask -> endNode`
Within the script tasks I have a simple java method call.

Before starting the jbpm process, registered an event listner

```
EventListner listner = new EventListner();
ksession.addEventListener(listner);

ksession.startProcess(processName);
```

There is a custom EventListner class

```
@Override
public class EventListner extends DefaultProcessEventListener {
    public void afterProcessStarted(ProcessStartedEvent startEvent) {
    //Some code here
    }
}
```

While running the jbpm process,what I see,
the afterProcessStarted API is called after the Java method call within the first script task

Unable to figure it out.Need Help.Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

This is as expected, the after process started event is only triggered when everything that was the result of starting the process was completed.  It behaves as a stack.  See http://docs.jboss.org/jbpm/v6.2/userguide/ch05.html#d0e1828